# NoMethodError when trying to parse Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When trying to parse a string with format `"%m-%Y"` in my update action, the server respond with a 500 error code, that says:

```
NoMethodError in EncuestasController#update
undefined method 'call' for Mon, 01 Jan -4712:Date Did you mean? caller
```

But, in rails console works fine:

```
ccaballero@konecta:~$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 10081
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
irb(main):001:0> f1 = "03-2017"
=> "03-2017"
irb(main):002:0> DateTime.strptime(f1, "%m-%Y")
=> Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00 +0000
irb(main):003:0>
```

Controller code as follows:

```
def update
    e = params[:encuesta]
    f1 = e[:fecha_inicio].to_s
    f2 = e[:fecha_fin].to_s
    f_inicio = Date.strptime(f1, "%m-%Y")
    f_fin = Date.strptime.(f2,"%m-%Y")
    p @encuesta.fecha_inicio
    p @encuesta.fecha_fin
    @encuesta.update_attributes(encuesta_params)
    @encuesta.update(fecha_inicio: f_inicio)
    @encuesta.update(fecha_fin: f_fin)    
    redirect_to encuestas_path, notice: "Encuesta editada correctamente"
  end
```

The line that raises the error is: `f_inicio = Date.strptime(f1, "%m-%Y")`
Params hash is correct in the controller 
Am I doing something wrong in the controller?
Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**
I discover what's wrong. It is the extra dot an the end of strptime in `f_fin = Date.strptime.(f2,"%m-%Y")`

Comment: In console you are using `DateTime`.

Comment: I was trying both ways, but already found the bug. Thanks!